# application not installed error on android

Tags: android, apk

I have been downloading different apk files and putting them on my android device with no problem.  however, there is one apk that has the error "application not installed."  i have tried downloading different versions of this from the internet (even using ones that other friends have used and worked for them).  i can't seem to figure out why this ONE apk file will download on my phone but not install.  i don't quite understand all this "signed" and "unsigned" business, but i figured if my friends have used the same exact apk it should work.  any ideas why this one app is causing me such a headache?

Comment: does your device supports the version of the downloaded apk??

Answer (score 1):

Okay firstly about singed and unsigned apps, a signed app has a special key from the developer saying "This is an official app from an official developer" unsigned apps will usually not install for security reasons. If you get the "application not installed" message from a signed your phone is not supported by the app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you uninstalled the currently installed version of the app? I've noticed that a few of my users get that message, and most of the time it's related to there already being an installed version. I'm not sure what's really behind *this*, but it usually helps out.

Comment: Could also be the solution. ;-)